# Check the status of a remote PC using telnet

Tags: python, python-3.x, telnet

How can I check the status of a remote PC using `telnet` from a python script?

Comment: maybe take a look to ``nmap``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has to be telnet, you can use the built-in [`telnetlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html):

```
from socketlib import timeout
from telnetlib import Telnet

try:
    Telnet("example.com", 23, 5)  # Timeout duration is 5 seconds
    print("Connected")
except timeout:
    print("Timed out")
```